# Is there a better way to deal with long file paths for copy-pasting files?

Tags: linux, terminal

My problem with the `cp` command is that I have to remember both paths to type them in one go and if I forgot what directory comes next, I can't look it up (I'd have to erase the command I've typed so far, navigate to that directory and use `ls`, then go back and try not to forget the path this time).

So I'm wondering if there is a way to navigate to one directory, execute something like `copy <file>`, then go to another directory and do `paste .`

Or any other way to avoid this problem

Comment: Doesn't your shell have completion support? If not, you may want to consider switching to zsh or fish (even bash has acceptable completion support these days).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It only completes when I type the beginning of the file name (and there's only one file that starts with that prefix). But even then, there can be like 100 files in a directory,

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: default on ubuntu

Comment: Shells like zsh or fish can be configured to offer browsable coloured completion lists which you navigate with the arrow keys. `fish` does it by default. In `zsh`, see `compinstall` to tune completion to your taste.

Comment: For such cases, maybe using Midnight Commander (mc) is better (package `mc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting TAB key twice.

Majority of modern terminals have ability to copy-paste text from the screen. Try selecting text with a mouse and RightClick...

There are always GUI version of file managers, which works exactly like you described.

There are text-based file managers which work inside the terminal (Midnight Commander, FAR Manager, many other).

Comment: >"TAB key twice" oh, that's cool, thanks! >"GUI version" I'm trying to use the terminal more :)

Comment: @splaytreez, the main idea of Linux - each task should be done by the best tool. If your task is not easily done in one tool, there is no shame to switch to better tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can move to beginning / end of command line in bash by typing Control + A / Control + E. Using it with a comment can be nifty. Put a '#' to execute it as a comment in bash, and keep it in history.

Example (_ -> represents cursor):

```
$ cp fileA _
type Control + A
$ _cp fileA
$ #cp fileA
$ cd /pathtofileB
press up arrow key for last command
$ #cp fileA
press Control + A again..remove hash
$ cp fileA
press Control + E
$ cp fileA fileB
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash you could do:

```
cp /original/path/{*.something,*otherthing*} /destination/dir/
```

if you want to "move" to the original path and do copies toward a destination dir you could do:

```
destdir="/destination/dir/"
cd /original/path
cp whatever "$destdir"
```